# Stop loss and exit incorrectly in strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

I used exit limit order and stop loss order in the following code, but in some trades it exceeds the specified values. Why is list of trades incorrect?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © edithblack2002

//@version=4
strategy("MACD Histogram", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true, pyramiding=1)

// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)
longProfitPerc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)",
     type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.5) / 100

shortProfitPerc = input(title="Short Take Profit (%)",
     type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.5) / 100
     
exitStopPerc = input(title="ExitStopPerc (%)",
     type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) / 100
     
// Figure out take profit price
longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)
ExitStopPriceLong = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - exitStopPerc)
ExitStopPriceShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + exitStopPerc)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price, color=color.white)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input(title="Oscillator MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input(title="Signal Line MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

// write minimum histogram
// miniHis = input(title="write minimum histogram", type=input.float, defval=0.0002)
miniHis = 0.0002
if hist < 0.00001 and hist > 0.000001 
    miniHis := 0.000002
if hist < 0.0001 and hist > 0.00001 
    miniHis := 0.00002
if hist < 0.001 and hist > 0.0001 
    miniHis := 0.0002
if hist < 0.01 and hist > 0.001
    miniHis := 0.002
if hist < 0.1 and hist > 0.01 
    miniHis := 0.02
if hist < 1 and hist > 0.1 
    miniHis := 0.2

// plot(syminfo.mintick)
longCondition = ((hist[1] > miniHis) and (hist) >= (hist[1] * 2) and (hist[2] <= 0))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="My Long Entry Id", limit=longExitPrice, stop=ExitStopPriceLong)

// shortCondition = ((hist[1] < -miniHis) and (hist) <= (hist[1] * 2) and (hist[2] >= 0))
// if (shortCondition)
//     strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
// if (strategy.position_size < 0)
//     strategy.exit(id="My Short Entry Id", limit=shortExitPrice, stop=ExitStopPriceShort)
```

Why did the pine script interpreter in the image below leave the position later in some cases? While I put limit order and stop loss

image from list of trades :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15aXy.jpg)

Comment: Please take screenshots with `longExitPrice`,  `ExitStopPriceLong` plots or provide your `longCondition`. There is nothing wrong in the image that you attached

Comment: @StarrLucky Thank you very much for answering
I put the full code
And I added to the description